# Change div background color after click

Tags: jquery

I'm new in jQuery.

How can I change the `div.card-header` background color when I click on the button (.selectBtn) ?

I have several box like this.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card bordered">
    <div class="card-header"> <span class="card-title">Item 1</span> </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action clearfix">
      <div class="pull-right"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-link black-text selectBtn">Select</a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I tried:

```
<script charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectBtn').click(function(event) {
      // alert alert-danger
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).find('.card-header').css('background-color', 'red');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.card-header` is not a sub element(child) of `.selectBtn`, it's more like a uncle.
So you need to transverse it all the way up by navigating to the it's `parent` and then find it's corresponding `sibling`.

```
$('.selectBtn').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('.card-action') // selects the parent .card-action of .selectBtn, you can use .parent() too for that
   .siblings('.card-header').css('background-color', 'red'); // selects the sibling .card-header of .card-action 
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/71hgeqnb/12/

Comment: Yup. Didn't look close enough. Fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I mentioned in my message that I have several boxes and your code actually select all of them : https://jsfiddle.net/71hgeqnb/10/. Thanks.

Comment: @J.Doe: Updated answer

Comment: Sure. Happy Friday :)

Answer (score 0):

u can do this,

add onclick to the link and create the function that calls it

`<a href="#" class="btn btn-link black-text selectBtn" onclick="ChangeColor();">Select</a>`

`function ChangeColor(){
     $('.card-header').css('background-color', 'red');
  }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectBtn').click(function(event) {
      // alert alert-danger
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.card-header').css('background-color', 'red');
    });
  });
</script>

<body>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card bordered">
    <div class="card-header"> <span class="card-title">Item 1</span> </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action clearfix">
      <div class="pull-right"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-link black-text selectBtn">Select</a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```